# How to make the custom grid url in the Magento

Tags: magento

I have created my custom module. I have displayed my all values from the database table into this grid. The grid works fine. However, in the edit link URL, I want to pass my custom params. The current URL looks like.

```
http://example.com/index.php/xyz/adminhtml_mymodule/edit/id/32/key/cf9639d403c328b26678fb7fa8f78cc5/
```

I want to pass the another parameter in this url.

For this I try the following

```
'url' => array('base'=> '*/*/edit','params'=>array('store'=>5)),
```

Now my url look's like

```
http://example.com/index.php/xyz/adminhtml_mymodule/edit/id/32/store/5/key/cf9639d403c328b26678fb7fa8f78cc5/
```

Which will be fine if i will pass the store param value 5 dynamically.

I want to pass the store dynamically form my current row. How can I get this current row value(store_id)

Can somebody help me in this?

Comment: you can directly use this grid function $row->getStoreId() to retieve current row store id

Comment: Well, i give the following error to me..Fatal error: Call to a member function getStoreId() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\PayAir-P1\branches\1.7.0.1\app\code\community\Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Grid.php on line 68

Comment: print your $row object and see what are you getting in getRowUrl() function

Comment: its gives me nothing...however, getRowUrl($row) function is working fine and returning the exact result what i want..public function getRowUrl($row)
  {
      return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId(),'store' => $row->getStoreId()));
  }

Comment: Can you tell me from where this function get passed?

Comment: If you want to passed store id parameter then You can change in rowurl function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this one

```
$this->addColumn('action',
        array(
            'header'    =>  Mage::helper('helperGroupClassName')->__('Action'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'type'      => 'action',
            'getter'    => 'getId',
            'actions'   => array(
                array(
                    'caption'   => Mage::helper('helperGroupClassName')->__('Edit'),
                    'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit', 'params' => array('store_id' => $this->getStoreId())),
                    'field'     => 'id'
                )
            ),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false,
            'index'     => 'stores',
            'is_system' => true,
    ));
```

Comment: it still not giving the store_id.